# Check if 2 Users are in the same array and compare their ranks in MongoDB (Pymongo)

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, dictionary, pymongo

I'm having difficulties with a specific task in Python and MongoDB. Firstly, I have some user data stored as objects in a MongoDB Array, and the first thing I need to do is check to see if 2 users are in the same array. If they are, **I need to check if one user's rank is higher than the other's. If the user's rank is higher, then he is allowed to kick the other user. Otherwise, the user is told that he needs to have a higher rank than the targeted user.** In this example there are only 2 users, but in reality there are many many users and 2 are selected based off a sent command in discord, so I can't just do array[0], array[1]. The data is stored like this:

```
  

    {
        _id: ObjectId("62464e3e75c6d843a338993b"),
        Name: 'Team',
        Members: [ 
            { 
                User: Long("699724378526580848"), 
                Rank: 4 
            } 
        ]
    }
```

If it's possible to check if the users are both in the same array using just one query, that would be great. If not, then whatever is the most efficient way will work.

Comment: Please post your code as formatted text and not as an image: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Okay, just did that.

Comment: Thanks :) it makes it easier for us to help you

Comment: Yes of course :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [$all](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/all/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { "Members.User": { $all: [ 123, 456 ] } }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$Members"
  },
  {
    $sort: { "Members.Rank": -1 }
  },
  {
    $limit: 1
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jUe7lq7G5wN)

Comment: Thank you! Would you happen to know how to do the ranks part?

Comment: @rolandsafiyati what kind of result do you want. Show me in your question by editing it. Make sure it's a valid json.

Comment: Alright, I edited the question and put the part needed in bold.

Comment: @rolandsafiyati show a `valid json` as expected result would be better than just word

Comment: @rolandsafiyati OK, I see, so basically you want to keep only one whose rank is greater right

Comment: @rolandsafiyati I update my answer

Comment: So right after checking if both user's exist in the same array, I'm trying to make an if statement that checks if the user running the command's rank is higher than the user's rank he's targeting. If his rank is higher, then the user with the lower rank is kicked. Otherwise, the user running the command is told his rank isn't high enough and the command ends without kicking.

Comment: @rolandsafiyati is my new answer correct ?

Comment: It looks like it would be. Only thing is how would I make it tell the user if his rank isn't high enough to kick?

Comment: @rolandsafiyati Since it's correct, it would be appreciate to accept this answer. You could make it in application level. In this case, if you want to check user 456. Then the result tell you only user 123 is left. So you can tell user 456. His rank isn't high enough.

Comment: Is there a way to match this pseudo code
`if user1 and user2 not in Members:` 
`print("That user isn't in this team")`
`elif user1_rank > user2_rank:`
`kick_user`
I'm looking for the order in here. I'll mark it as correct after.

Comment: Sure but you had better make it in application level instead of DB level.

Comment: Yes since I'm on python I was wondering if I could make as little queries as possible by making the conditions application level. So first query the database to see if both users are in the database (you answered this with $all which worked perfectly). Next I need to check the ranks before pulling the user from the array and this is what I'm struggling with now.